# Lack of permission on iOS photo album using Cordova

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, permissions, camera

I am developing an app using Cordova 4.3.0. I need to provide access for the user to select a picture from their photo album, and I'm using the following code:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI) {
    //success
}, function(message) {
    //error
}, {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
});
```

When this code is invoked on iOS, I'm receiving the message:

[image: iOS Screenshot]

In privacy settings the app is enabled in Camera, but doesn't appear in Photos. This error does not occur on the XCode simulator. I tried the last version of the [Camera Apache plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/) (0.3.6) and the last development one (1.0.1-dev), with the same result.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to add something on `config.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb solution. The device I had access to had restrictions enabled for the photo album.

The iOS simply says you can't access the pictures, without explaining the reason.

Restriction removed, problem solved.